# Find the missing piece to complete the pattern

Tags: pattern

[image: ftmp]

Complete the pattern, what figure (1-9) should be at the question mark?

*Created by myself*

Comment: Why do you let us wait with the solution(s) Mr. Plarsen?

Comment: I am new here and thought that was part of the idea? to wait until someone give the correct answer?

Comment: Oh yes that's right of course! But it would be nice if you could write in the comments of an answer if it's correct or not.

Comment: @watchme oh, sorry I misunderstood. I am on to it right away

Answer (score 1):

I believe it's:

> Bottom middle.

Based on:

> Pattern matches from top to bottom, diagonal from top left to bottom right, and left to right. + is due to missing option with 2 triangles and rotation.

Comment: Close, you have choosen one with the correct number of inner figure positions. One hint is that both the 4 position cube structures and the 6 position pyramid structures all is someway (sometimes hidden behind others) containing 9 sub-figures that is mapped onto the available 4 or 6 positions. The pattern is quite complex to visualize because of the dynamic limit of available positions.